# How do I fix my selection sort? only returns "0"

Tags: c++

Hello I'm fairly new to c++ coding as a first-year comp sci major and I am working on a lab in which I have to fill an array and do multiple types of sorting and searching, and I'm stuck on selection sort as my code will only return 0. any help is appreciated! <3 ^_^

**HOW TO USE**

1. FIRST DO OPTION "1" TO FILL IN ARRAY
2. ENTER 10 NUMBERS (PREFERABLY IN MESSED UP ORDER
3. CODE WILL RETURN TO MAIN MENU
4. DO OPTION "4"

**CODE**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

//Fill In Array
void fillData(int array[])
{

    cout << "Enter 10 numbers to fill in the array ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cin >> array[i];
    }
}
//Linear search 
int lSearch(int array[], int size, int target, int option)
{
    if (option == 2)
    {
        cout << "What number are you looking for?";
        cin >> target;

        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
            if (target == array[index])
                return index;
    }
    else
        return -1;
}
//Binary Search 
int bSearch(const int array[], int size, int value)
{
    cout << "What number are you looking for?";
    cin >> value; 
    
    int first = 0,
        last = size - 1,
        middle,
        position = -1;
    bool found = false; 
    while (!found && first <= last)
    {
        middle = (first + last) / 2; 
        if (array[middle] == value)
        {
            found = true;
            position = middle;
        }
        else if (array[middle] > value)
            last = middle - 1;
        else
            first = middle + 1;
    }
    return position;
}
//Selection Sort
int selectionSort(int array[], int size )
{
    int i{};
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int smallest = array[i]; 
        int smallestIndex = i; 
        
        for (int m = i; m < 10; m++)
        {
            if(array[m] < smallest)
                {
                    smallest = array[m]; 
                    smallestIndex = m; 
                }
        }
        swap(array[i], array[smallestIndex]); 
    }
    return array[i]; 
    
}

//everything together 
int main()
{
    int option{};
    int array[10];
    int result;
    int target{};
    //display menu
    do
    {
        cout << setw(20) << setfill('-') << "" << "MENU" << setw(20) << setfill('-') << "" << endl;
        cout << "1. Fill Data" << endl;
        cout << "2. Linear Search" << endl;
        cout << "3. Binary Search" << endl;
        cout << "4. Selection Sort" << endl;
        cout << "5. Bubble Sort" << endl;
        cout << "6. Display Data" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Which Option Would you like to do? ";
        cin >> option;
        cout << endl; 
        
        switch (option)
        {
        case 1:
            fillData(array);
            break;

        case 2:
            //Linear search
            result = lSearch(array, 10, target, option);
            cout << " That number is inside of index # " << result << endl;
            cout << endl;
            break;
        
        case 3: 
            //Binary search
            result = bSearch(array, 10, option);
            cout << " That number is inside of index # " <<  result << endl;

        case 4:
            //Selection Sort
            result = selectionSort(array, 10);  
            cout << "selection sort is " << result << endl; 
        
        }




    } while (option != -1);
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I reopened the question. This isn't a problem that can be solved by a debugger. The problem here is a misunderstanding of C++ (or programming languages in general).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask yourself what the result of sorting an array should be. I hope you can see that it should be another array. If you sort the array `{4, 8, 1, 3}` (for instance) into ascending order the result is the sorted array `{1, 3, 4, 8}`.

But your code assumes that the result of a sorting an array is an integer.

```
result = selectionSort(array, 10);
```

This is fine for your other operations like linear search or binary search where the result is an array index, but for sorting it just makes no sense at all.

The `selectionSort` function you've written looks OK (although I haven't tested it). It's what's known as a *in-place sort*, which means that instead of creating and returning a new array it modifies the array it has been given so that array itself is sorted.

What this means for your program is that your sorting routine doesn't have to return anything at all. Instead it sorts the array it has been given. So change your `selectionSort` function to return nothing

```
void selectionSort(int array[], int size )
```

and change the code after you've called `selectionSort` to print the array that was passed to `selectionSort`, which should now be sorted. Something like this

```
selectionSort(array, 10); 
cout << "selection sort is";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    cout << ' ' << array[i];
cout << '\n';
```